# Question about quantum physics / diatomic molecule electron

Tags: quantum-mechanics

In part c I saw a solution state that in even state the electron tends to draw them together promoting the bonding while the opposite for excited (odd) state
Why is that the case? What is the effect of the state on the bonding or push the nuclei apart [image: 173111]

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the sketches!! Once you have them you can estimate the energy from the curvature of the sketch in between the wells where $V=0$. The point is that the important distinction between a ground state and a first excited state is the presence or absence of a zero in the wavefunction. Because of the symmetry it must fall in the centre at $x=0$. So start the sketch at $x=0$ either with $\psi>0$ and zero gradient or $\psi=0$ and non-zero gradient, and complete it on one side. On the other side it follows from the symmetry.